# How to set cookies in test if I do not create a "page" and "context" in the test, but receive it

Tags: javascript, testing, cookies, automated-tests, playwright

I have a config file that contains projects with browsers:

```
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Mobile Chrome Pixel 5',
      use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'], locale: 'en-EN' },
    },
    {
      name: 'Mobile Safari Pixel 5',
      use: { ...devices['Pixel 5'], locale: 'en-EN' },
    },
  ],
```

And I have a test in which I receive the page and content and add cookies:

```
test('My test', async ({page, context}) =>{
  await context.addCookies([
    { name: 'sessionid', value: 'random', path: '/', domain: 'someDomain' }
  ]);
  await console.log(context.cookies())
  //some test code
})
```

In all cookie setting solutions and questions, the "context", "browser" and "page" variables were created directly in the test, which I found strange, since I use multiple browsers for tests and use "projects" in the config file, so I can't create a browser variable in the test.

I get "context" in the test, but looking at the data from the console, it is not what I need, and the cookies I need are not set in "context".
What is the problem and what am I doing wrong?